# WSO2 APIM 4 JMS Provider is not yet started

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm getting the below error after starting a new WSO2 APIM 4 instance.

```
TID: [-1] [] [2022-01-09 09:19:45,277] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.jms.JMSListener} - JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start the JMS provider now.
TID: [-1] [] [2022-01-09 09:19:45,277] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.jms.JMSListener} - Connection attempt : 4 for JMS Provider failed. Next retry in 160 seconds
```

OS: CentOS 7.9
Java: OpenJDK 8
wso2apim version :4.0.0

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using super admin password containing (@) issue resolved by removing the (@) from my admin password.
API amanger uses this password in connection strings to connect to JMS .